# get () get() returned more than one SubRegion, DJango cities_light

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Cities_light

My files that I want to include

```
 CITIES_LIGHT_TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ['fr','en']
 CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_COUNTRIES = ['CA','US']
 CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_CITY_TYPES = ['PPL', 'PPLA', 'PPLA2', 'PPLA3', 'PPLA4', 'PPLC', 'PPLF', 'PPLG', 'PPLL', 'PPLR', 'PPLS', 'STLMT',]
```

When I run the command

```
 python manage.py cities_light
```

I just got the error of

```
 cities_light.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one SubRegion -- it returned 35!
```

Any solutions? I want the all cities of Canada and USA

Answer (score 0):

Briefly went over the documentation and it should work. Did you forget to migrate? I’m asking because they mention using a ci/cd pipeline and if any issue exists they should have caught on it.
Also there were some issues with MySQL db but it doesn’t seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes, I did migrate it shows me the cities of canada but not USA. and one thing , I am using postgresql

Comment: With the help of documentation, I did all. My database is all set. I have cities of canada but not USA cities.

Comment: Postgres is the recommendation with UTF-8 charset. Try this also: `./manage.py cities_light —force-all`

Comment: Otherwise just switch to [django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) if still doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

get()  cannot handle that many!. Use app.models.ModelName.objects.all()

then perform conditional statements on the returned query.

Eg:

```py
   from myapp.models import MyModel
   query_results = MyModel.objects.all()
   for result in query_result:
       if result.name == 'Steve':
          print('Steve Number: ', result.number)
          print('Steve email: ', result.email)
       else:
          print('Not steve :(')
```